# How to elegantly transition images in slide show?

Tags: objective-c, ios, image, uiview

After some research on here I found a solution to creating a slide show of images in an iphone app.  All working fine, currently the images show one after another.

My question is, can I make the images cross dissolve/fade rather than just appearing, and if so could I get some advice on that.

My Code

.m

```
 }
 int topIndex = 0, prevTopIndex = 1; 
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {


imagebottom = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160,240)];
[self.view addSubview:imagebottom];

imagetop = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,160,240)];
[self.view addSubview:imagetop];

imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"],
              [UIImage imageNamed:@"ip2.png"],
              nil];


NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5.0
                                         target:self
                                       selector:@selector(onTimer)
                                       userInfo:nil
                                        repeats:YES];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[timer fire];

[super viewDidLoad];
}

-(void)onTimer{
if(topIndex %2 == 0){
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^
     {
         imagebottom.alpha = 0.0;
     }];
    imagetop.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:prevTopIndex];
    imagetop.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:topIndex];
}else{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:5.0 animations:^
     {
         imagetop.alpha = 1.0;
     }];
    imagetop.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:topIndex];
    imagebottom.image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:prevTopIndex];
}
prevTopIndex = topIndex;
if(topIndex == [imageArray count]-1){
    topIndex = 0;
}else{
    topIndex++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of options. If you have a "container" view, you can make a new UIImageView transparent (alpha = 0), then use a UIView animation block to fade one image in and the other out (or leave alpha = 1 on both and slide one in from any side you want.

For instance, you have your main view, self.view. You have one UIImageView *oldView, that is now at rect (0,0,320,100) and you want to slide it to the right as you slide a newView imageView in. First you set the newView frame to (-320,0,320,100) then [self.view addSubview newView]. To animate the change:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2 animations:^
  {
     oldView.frame = CGRectMake(320, 0, 320, 100);
     newView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320, 100);
  }
completion:^(BOOL finished)
  {
    [oldView removeFromSuperView];
  } ];
```

You also have the option of using UiView's

```
+ (void)transitionFromView:(UIView *)fromView toView:(UIView *)toView duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

which gives you more/different options (and its less work too!). For instance, using the same basic objects in the first example, but the newView having the same frame as the oldView:

```
transitionFromView:oldView toView:newView duration:2 options: UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve completion:^(BOOL finished)) { /*whatever*/}];
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, im having trouble understanding how to apply that to my code could you expand on that at all, second version sounds good